# C: Save a car art from a file in a two dimensional char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

I want to get a ascii art of a car from a file. How do I save it in a two dimensional string? Every single car of the struct should have the car art in the look array. The other indexes of the array should be null.

```
int i = 0;
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;

  char c[20];
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("car.txt", "r");

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {

    rewind(fp);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    arr[i].drives = 0;
    arr[i].x = 0;
    arr[i].y = 0;
    arr[i].fuel = 0;
    arr[i].maxfuel = 40;
    arr[i].lane = 0;
    arr[i].starttime = 0;

    fgets(c, 20, fp);

    while(c != EOF) {
      for(x = 0; x < 20; x += 1) {
        if(x < length(c)){
          arr[i].look[x][y] = c[x];
        } else {
          arr[i].look[x][y] = 'r';
        }
      }

      fgets(c, 20, fp);

      y += 1;
    }
```

It prints some weired letters. Like &, %, ° and so on.

Comment: `while(c != EOF) {` <<-- what does your compiler say?

Comment: warning comparison between integer and pointer

Comment: Right. You're comparing a pointer to your array `c` to EOF. Check the documentation for `fgets` to properly check results of the read. Always read the documentation for functions you are using to get some understanding as to how to use them and how they behave. Writing code based upon guessing and vague pattern matching with how you think  you've seen it used is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, I will do it